# Adding Publisher Action to visual force page

Tags: salesforce1-app

I've override object view page in order to customize look and feel on sf1. Is it possible to add "Publisher Action button(+)"? The (+) icon shows up when using default layout but it disppears when override default action

Comment: How do you add the '+' to a visualforce page in SF1?

Answer (score 1):

The code turns off the Publisher for VF pages.

You can't do it in a supported way. I've filed a feature request to allow this. In the mean time, I wrote you a function to try.

```
var unsupportedShowMdp=function(a){
    SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator.fireContainerEvent(
        "one:updateMDPVisibility",{show:a}
    )
};

// Use it like this

unsupportedShowMdp(true);
```

Unsupported. I give it a 80% chance it stops working next release, but by then we might have a supported way of doing this.