# Display Publisher Actions (Upload file to feed) on Visualforce page in Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, chatter, salesforce1-app, mobile, upload

I have a feed-enabled CustomObject__c which I want to expose via Salesforce1. For some reasons I have an override for the View page that is a used for desktop and mobile devices.

On of the use cases of this page is that users post files in the feed of those object.

As I am using the overriden VF page in Mobile the user has no "+" Buttton to access Publisher actions.

Is there any way to activate / embed it so that I am not force to use standard layout on mobile devices?

Comment: I think + button(publisher action) can't be displayed when overriding the action with vf page

Comment: On page 84 of the implementation guide (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/salesforce1_guide.pdf) they show it on a visualforce page.  I kind of feel like that is a mock up and not real functionality as it is not in other visualforce pages in the doc

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40312/adding-publisher-action-to-visual-force-page