# Accessing an object's actions on a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom object, Site, with an action that creates a new child record, Holiday, for a Site.  I have a Visualforce page that uses the Site standard controller to display a limited subset of Site fields.  I'd like to make use of that action in the Visualforce page.  Is there a way to surface an object's actions in a Visualforce page?  I tried the following,

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!New_Holiday}" value="New Holiday" id="theButton"/>
```

but I'm getting an "unknown method..." error which makes me think I'd need to make a controller extension (and code for the action).  I can created the extension if that's how I need to do this, but I'm hoping to find a way to use an existing action.

I've found plenty of info about using visualforce pages as actions, but nothing yet about surfacing actions in VF pages.

Note: I'm mainly intending this for use in Salesforce1, but it won't bother me if this action is available in regular Salesforce and Salesforce1.

**Edited to add**
The following code works:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.SiteProgram__c.New_Holidaybtn)}" value="Create New Holiday" id="whatevs"></apex:commandButton>
```

It appears that object-specific actions are not accessible via $Action, but buttons and links are.

Answer (score 8):

The new action doesn't appear in the list of [Standard Controller Actions](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_std_actions.htm) but you should be able to use a [global action](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_action_valid_values.htm) like:
`<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Holiday__c.New)}">Create New Holiday</apex:outputLink>`

You could also create an object specific action on Site by following these steps from the [Publishers Action Implementation Guide](http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/actions_impl_guide.pdf):

> To create object-specific actions:
>   1. From Setup, click Customize, choose the object for which you want to create an action, and click Buttons, Links, and Actions.
>   2. Click New Action.
>   3. Select the type of action you want to create.
>   4. Customize the action:
>   • For a Create a Record action, select the type of object to create.
>   ◊ If there’s more than one record type for
>   that object, select the one you want to use for records created
>   through this action.
>   ◊ If there’s more than one relationship between
>   the object on which you’re creating the action and the target object,
>   select the field you want to populate automatically when a record is
>   created. (For objects with only one relationship, the Relationship
>   Field is set by default.)

Comment: After reading your answer, I had hopes that something like "<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.SiteProgram__c.New_Holiday)}">Create New Holiday</apex:outputLink>" might work for object-specific links, but using the name of the action after the object name in the outputlink does not work for me.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood your question, that will work for custom buttons, but not actions. I did some digging and found this question... http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40312/adding-publisher-action-to-visual-force-page is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'll give it a try as a custom button and let you know what I find.

Comment: I tested the url for with a custom button and that does work but I couldn't get it to work with an action.

Comment: Yes, setting this up as a button works.  There's one thing still missing.  My "{!varname}" values from the button  don't get filled in.  I should probably make how to get those right a separate question.

Comment: Yes, it might help to open a new question with the code for the button.